# Ruby on Rails 4.0 button query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Rails and have a question.

I have a Person model and a Contacts model. They have the association Person has_many Contacts. On my views/persons/index.html.erb page I want to add a button next to person that renders all of the contacts that belongs to that person. Specifically, I'm not sure how to pass the person's ID into a query to find and render all the contacts that belong to that person. I know how to add in a button, but I'm not sure how to code the aforementioned.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the link_to method and style it as a button if you need to.

```
<%= link_to @person.name, person_contacts_path(@person) %>
```

will generate a link '/person/1/contacts'

In routes.rb

```
resources :persons do
  resources :contacts
end
```

On routing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources